# Simplifying the alternating sum of n squares

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, summation, triangular-numbers

This question is based on a curious problem from Donald Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming, exercise 7 to chapter 1.2.1. It's stated as the following:

> Formulate and prove by induction a rule for the sums $1^2$, $2^2-1^2$, $3^2-2^2+1^2$, $4^2-3^2+2^2-1^2$, $5^2-4^2+3^2-2^2+1^2$, etc.

Please note that during this simplification I assume that I know nothing neither about the sum of first $n$ natural numbers, nor about triangular numbers. (1)

Below is my attempt to build a solution.

### Formulation

Let's take as an observation that these sums are following a couple of rules:

- The signs alternate in such way that summands with odd indices are positive, and the rest negative.
- The sum goes from $n$ to $1$.

Thus, we can express alternating signs by multiplying each summand by $(-1)^k$ where $k$ is even for summands with odd indices and odd for summands with even indices, which makes it possible to say $k=j-1$ where $j$ is the index of the current summand because the first summand is odd so we need an even power.

***Sub-question:** can we go $k=j+1$ here instead and if yes, then why?*

Taking the largest summand as $n^2$, we can express the rest of them as $(n-1)^2$, $(n-2)^2$, and so on all the way down to $(n-(n-1))^2$, which is $1^2$, for the last summand.

Expressing the first index as $n-n$ and the last one as $n$, this gives us a formula:

$$(-1)^{n-n}n^2+(-1)^{n-(n-1)}(n-1)^2+...+(-1)^{n}(n-(n-1))^2$$

Note that it's possible to express each of the terms in brackets with indexes, which provides us way prettier formula to look at:

$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^j(n-j)^2$$

### Simplification

As with any sum with alternating signs, it's always a good idea to group them in pairs and try to find partial sums. Here, it can be done by the difference of squares formula. Below are results for some first pairs of summands:

$$n^2-(n-1)^2=(n-n+1)(n+n-1)=2n-1\\
(n-2)^2-(n-3)^2=2n-5\\
(n-4)^2-(n-5)^2=2n-9$$

Thus, by finding the partial sums above, we've transformed the sum to the following form:

$$(2n-1)+(2n-5)+(2n-9)+...$$

If $n$ is odd, then the amount of summands is also odd, thus the last summand will not get a pair, and will remain the same. If $n$ is even, then all summands will get grouped into pairs. So, for the general case, a new sum will have $k=\left\lceil\dfrac{n}2\right\rceil$ summands.

For the even case, I can find partial sums again:

$$(2n-1)=1(2n-1)\\
(2n-1)+(2n-5)=2(2n-3)\\
(2n-1)+(2n-5)+(2n-9)=3(2n-5)$$

...and so on.

With $n=2k$, this directly leads to a formula for sum of $k$ such summands: $k(4k-(2k+1))=k(2k-1)$. Substituting $k=\dfrac{n}2$, we get the formula $\dfrac{n(n-1)}2$.

I can't derive the same formula for the 'odd summands' case, neither I can go further to get to $1+2+...+n$.

### Proving by induction

A good proof can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Triangular_Number_as_Alternating_Sum_and_Difference_of_Squares). However, it supposes that the $\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$ is already known, thus I must obtain it before usage, which I haven't done fully.

### The question

How do I come to the $\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$ or $1+2+...+n$, knowing neither of these sums? E.g. through equivalent transformations of the sum formula obtained in the first section of this question. If this helps, I've seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162190/proof-alternating-sum-of-squares-is-alternating-sign-of-sum), but I don't have such subtraction in my case (or I'm plain ignoring it right in my sight).

Comment: $n^2-(n-1)^2=(n+n-1)(n-(n-1))=n+(n-1)$.

Comment: @mathlove that's of course true, but how does this fact leads to a sum? Proving by induction, perhaps? As I think, this also creates additional question about 'what do we do with odd amount of summands where the last summand stays the same?'. Perhaps it's the last $1$ we need in that case?

Comment: You wrote $n^2-(n-1)^2=2n-1$, but I wrote $n^2-(n-1)^2=n+(n-1)$ which is the sum of two consecutive integers. Does this help?

Comment: The thing about proofs by induction is that they do expect you to have a formula in mind to prove. If the exercise doesn't say "prove this sum is equivalent to  this formula," then you're expected to make an educated guess. So you calculate the first few sums, and you get $1,3,6,10,15$ and, hey, those look a lot like the triangular numbers! Let's see if we can make it happen. Then the thing that's hiding in plain sight is this: If we call the sum $S(n)$, and look at the next smaller and next larger sums, we see they satisfy $S(n)=n^2-S(n-1)$. $S(1)=1=(1)(2)/2$ is your base case for induction.

Comment: @mathlove it does! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your successive deductions. "How do I come with $n(n+1)/2$ ?": you cannot rediscover all,: as soon are you are operating in any domain, you must be "accompanied" either by a prior knowledge or by a coach (virtual or real...). It's in particular important to know also some keywords that help searching; here the first-aid keyword is "combinatorics" that I don't find in your keywords.

Comment: @JeanMarie One indeed cannot rediscover all, which is exactly why I'm asking the question. One thing I was always curious about is how different people discover different things. The more I know, the better I am at math, so why not? :) Combinatorics keyword also added, thanks!

Comment: We agree. The problem with self learning is that you can spend, hours, days trapped into a difficulty. Happily there are places like this one, forums of different styles where you can learn a lot ... but some difficulties are almost impossible to describe clearly to any remote audience. You need a teacher close to you ...

Comment: @Rusurano , JeanMarie - the keyword "rediscover"... I had about 2006 a fun time rediscovering the "sum-of-like-powers"-problem and found solutions exploratorily my way. It had become a nice adventure to sequentially come across all the ol'stuff from Bernoulli, Faulhaber, Euler etc. If you like to read an article based on my explorations look at http://go.helms-net.de/math/binomial_new/04_3_SummingOfLikePowers.pdf at my homepage. I've followed all the way the route on matrix-notation; par. 1.2) on page 5) begins with the binomial-theorem and might be a nice entry-point...

Comment: (...) and answer to the above question of "alternating-sum-of-like-powers" was one of the steps on the stair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an answer inside my question which slipped from my initial attention. I've got $n^2-(n-1)^2=2n-1$, which is correct. However, there is more to it. As *mathlove* has said, $2n-1=n+n-1=n+(n-1)$, which is a sum of two consecutive numbers.

Thus, $(n-2)^2-(n-3)^2=(n-2)+(n-3)$, and so on.
This way, the initial sum gets transformed into:

$[n^2-(n-1)^2]+[(n-2)^2-(n-3)^2]+...+1$

No matter whether the sum has odd or even amount of summands, we will **always** add 1. Here is the proof of that:

- Suppose the amount of summands is even. Then we have a pair for each summand, and the last pair will be transformed as $2^2-1^2=2+1$, which means we have $1$ added as the last summand.
- Now suppose the amount of summands is odd. In that case, the last summand won't have a pair, but if the amount of summands is odd, then $n$ is as well odd, then $(-1)^{n-1}=1$, and we still have $1$ added as the last summand.

Thus, we conclude that the following equality is correct:

$$(-1)^{n-n}n^2+(-1)^{n-(n-1)}(n-1)^2+...+(-1)^{n}(n-(n-1))^2=1+2+...+n$$